# location of tables in page

Tags: tables

I have the code below for a table creation but the table is appeared before the referred site.

Code:

```
\begin{table}
 \caption{The properties of the fitted linear model}
    \label{tab: varpar}
    \centering
    \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \texttt{Partial Sill} &\texttt{ Nugget} & \texttt{Range} & \texttt{Instant} & \texttt{Slope} \\ \hline
        0.30         & 0.19   & 408   & 0.0015  & 0     \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Moreover i have used `\clearpage` to avoid ploting of tables or figures in a new section.
And, the aforementioned code is cited in new section.
However, I would like to have tables as near as possible to the cited site.

Comment: did you tried using the `here` package and adding the `[H]` option like that: `\begin{table}[H]` this should force LaTeX to display the table where its defined

Comment: when I have used the [H] the tables placed after figures. Maybe [htbf] works.

Comment: You should probably read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) FAQ page `:)`

Comment: See in particular http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020 for the full detail

Answer (score 1):

Please always post complete small documents that show the problem. It is hard to guess were that float went (and the contents are irrelevant to the float positioning algorithm, you could replace the tabular by `\vspace{2\baselineskip}` to demonstrate the same effect.

You say the table appears too early. LaTeX can basically only move floats *later* in the document with the exception that it will by default place them at the top of the page on which they are defined, which can move them forward. You can prevent this option by loading the `flafter` package (part of the base LaTeX distribution) which ensures that a float always appears after its definition.